# Expression calculated at assembly time

Tags: computer-architecture, assembly

[image]

I don't understand the explanation. Doesn't the assembler have to calculate 3 * 4 + 5 so it takes longer to execute? Also since 3 * 4 +5 has more characters why does it not take more storage?

From problem 2 of:https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-004-computation-structures-spring-2017/c9/c9s3/isa_answers.pdf

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No it's from https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-004-computation-structures-spring-2017/c9/c9s3/isa_answers.pdf

Comment: You are confusing build/compile/assembly stage with executions stage. Build is slightly slower, but you do that only once. Executing is equally fast for both options and you usually do that many times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The assembler (compiler) has to calculate the constant at assembly time, so the compilation to binary is marginally slower. A human cannot tell the difference so the compilation time it takes is irrelevant.

The resulting assembly binary will be identical, so they are both equally sized and equally fast programs.

Comment: From the point of view of software development, it's good to put the calculation in the source code so it can be checked when modifications are necessary.
Even better, define sybolic constants so the expression is more easily understood and a change to a real-world value can be made in one place (the definition of the constant).